# Add newline after each key, value using JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add a newline after each key value pair in an object using JSON.stringify()

In my actual code I will be getting a lot of key value pairs and having the new lines makes it easier to read.

Example code is:

```
let test = {'key' : ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'keyTwo' : ['one', 'two', 'three']}

let testOne = JSON.stringify(test, null, '\t')

console.log(testOne)
```

outputs:

```
{
        "key": [
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
        ],
        "keyTwo": [
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
        ]
}
```

I want:

```
{
        "key": [
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
        ],
                                   // <----- newline here
        "keyTwo": [
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
        ]
}
```

I have tried

```
let test = {'key' : ['one', 'two', 'three'] + "\\n", 'keyTwo' : ['one', 'two', 'three']+ "\\n"}

let testOne = JSON.stringify(test, null, '\t\n')
```

Neither work

Comment: The result of `['one', 'two', 'three'] + "\\n"` is the string `'one,two,three\\n'`. It's not an array anymore. `JSON.stringify(test, null, '\t\n')` adds a newline after each key/value pair.

Comment: Please fix the format of your question. _"outputs:"_ and _"I want:"_ are not code and therefor shouldn't be formatted as such.

Comment: Why do you want the object as string in the first place? Isn't the collapsible view and the syntax highlighting from the console way easier to handle and grasp then just a plain piece of string?

Comment: @Andreas, I have fixed the format and I end up sending the output to a txt file not the console

Comment: Then add the newline, if you insist on it, in the editor/viewer of your choice. Messing with the format of JSON will only produce errors later on.

Comment: @Andreas Why do you think `JSON.stringify` was created....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const test = {'key' : ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'keyTwo' : ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'keyThree' : ['one', 'two', 'three']}

const testOne = JSON
    .stringify(test, null, "\t")
    .replaceAll(
        "],\n\t\"", 
        "],\n\n\t\""
    );
console.log(testOne);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this only works between the first two pairs, if there is a third (or more) key pair value it will not add the new line.

Comment: fixed with replaceAll()